# Get Local Date and Time GMT+8

Tags: javascript, timezone

Can somebody help me please.

I'm trying to get the date and time, it works but I need it be our local time GMT +8

Here's the piece of code:

```
// Get Current Date and Time

(async function () {
  
var today = new Date();
var date = today.getDate()+'-'+(today.getMonth()+1)+'-'+today.getFullYear();
var time = today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();
var d = date+' '+time;

  var response = {
    actions: [
      { 
        type: 'set_variable',
        data: { DateTimeNow: [d] }
      }
    ]
  };
  done(response); // This is required.
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Date.UTC() method for this case. See the console in following example

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/kavinduLanarolle/q3fc9ez2/6/)

```
var today = new Date();
const utcDate1 = new Date(Date.UTC(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth(), today.getDate(), today.getHours(), today.getMinutes(), today.getSeconds()));
console.log(utcDate1.toUTCString())
```